# why sizeof(0xF) is 4 bytes?

Tags: c++, integer, sizeof

I have following code,

```
unsigned short code = 0x12E0;
code = code & 0x0FFF;
```

In my CLion IDE, i am getting a warning that

> "Values of type `int` may not fit into the receiver type `unsigned short`"

If I put it like `code &= 0x0FFF;`, the warning is gone.

Why it is taking `0x0FFF` as `int`? The `sizeof(0xF)` is `4`, can someone explain why?

Comment: *"Why it is taking 0x0FFF as int?"* Because the standards mandate it. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: FWIW the compiler issuing this warning is junk. This kind of warning should be done by range analysis, not type.

Comment: You ask about `sizeof(0xF)` then you ask about `0xFFF` then you ask about `sizeof(0xF)` again?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit both gives you 4 bytes

Comment: @sajadkk: Why do you switch between the two examples as you talk?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit 0x0FFF is from the code, other one i asked generally

Comment: @R.. I strongly disagree. Assuming different integer types have the same size kills portability. I've done a migration from 16 bit int to 32 bit int, so I know that there will be a lot of work to fix it if they aren't separated. You do want compiler warnings when mixing types, even if they happen to match in size on *this* platform.

Comment: Huh? Here the value necessarily fits in int no matter what the implementation's definition of int is.

Comment: I compiled the code from the post with `cc -Wall -std=c11` and I got no warnings or errors (which is what I would expect). I think this is a junk compiler message as @R.. has already said. (Clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: @R.. I interpreted "This kind of warning..." as a general statement (and not just pertaining to this case). I then assumed (probably in error?) that you meant the ranges of the current platform.

Comment: @R.. Types do matter. Consider `if( (-1 & -1) < 0 )` versus `if( (-1 & 0xFFFFFFFF) < 0 )`. Both should give a result with a range that will fit inside `int`, yet in the latter case there is a silent change of signedness, changing the outcome of the code.

Comment: @Lundin: No, `-1 & 0xffffffff` does not fit in `int` (assuming 32-bit `int`). The resulting value is `0xffffffff` which is larger than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @R.. Upon which there is normally a conversion from 0xFFFFFFFF to the signed 2's complement equivalent, `-1`. But that conversion won't happen in my example simply because the integer constant `0xFFFFFFFF` is of type `unsigned int`, which means that the result of `-1 & 0xFFFFFFFF` is also unsigned int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integer constant `0x0FFF` is, like all integer constants, at least of type `int`. But it doesn't matter here.

In the expression `code & 0x0FFF`, both operands `code` and `0x0FFF` are subject to implicit integer promotion, *the integer promotion rules*. This applies to *small integer types*  such as `short`. So the `code`operand is always promoted to (at least) `int` regardless of the type of the other operand.

Therefore you will get the very same issue if you do this:

```
unsigned short code = 0x12E0;
unsigned short x = 0x0FFF;
code = code & x;
```

The compiler probably suppresses the warnings in the first two rows since it is just simple assignment. But in the last row there's a more complex expression and integer overflow could potentially be an issue. Overall, compilers tend to be inconsistent with these kind of warnings, since they aren't mandatory.

Pedantic but 100% safe code, free from implicit type conversions, would look like this:

```
code = (unsigned short) ((unsigned int)code & 0x0FFFu);
```

Comment: @sajadkk I would assume it is because of an inconsistency in the tool that generates the warning. `code &= 0x0FFF` is a "compound assignment" which is guaranteed to be the very same thing as `code = code & 0x0FFF`. You could file a bug report with the tool vendor.

Answer (score 3):

Because the type of an integer constant is determined to be the first that can contain it, and short simply isn't in the list of types. `int` is the first type that fits.

Quoting [N1570/6.4.4.1p5](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5):

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can be represented.
>
> ```
> Suffix | Decimal Constant | Octal or Hexadecimal Constant
> ------ | ---------------- | -----------------------------
> none   | int              | int 
>        | long int         | unsigned int
>        | long long int    | long int
>        |                  | unsigned long int
>        |                  | long long int
>        |                  | unsigned long long int
> ```

The table clearly specifies int as the first type, and not `short`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Nope, I'm saying the type of the constant is `int`. It just so happens the *value* fits in a `short` so it compiles with no warning.

Comment: @StoryTeller so i have to always cast like this code = (unsigned short) (code & 0x0FFF) ?

Comment: This isn't the reason for the compiler warning though.

Comment: @Lundin - It is however the reason for what sizeof gives.

Comment: @Lundin it is the IDE, that is giving the warning, not compiler

Comment: @StoryTeller If you wrote `code & (unsigned short)0x0FFF` you would still get the same warning. So this isn't the root cause.

Comment: @sajadkk Warnings come from compilers, linkers or static analyser tools. Not from IDEs.

Comment: @Lundin - The questions as they appear in the post are *"Why it is taking 0x0FFF as int? the sizeof(0xF) is 4, can someone explain why?"* - I do believe this standard reference answered that.

Comment: But the context is "why is `sizeof(x & y)` always at least 4 no matter what types I use for `x` and `y`".

Comment: @Lundin - I didn't understand it like that. But it's immaterial. There's your answer to cover that.

Answer (score 1):

Without any specific suffix attached, an integer constant like `0x12E0` or `0x0FFF` is of type `int`. They will be categorized as "hexadecimal constant" due to the prefix of `0x`.

Also, as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42762645/2173917), for an integer constant (to be specific, "*Octal or Hexadecimal constant*") with no explicit suffix, the type will be decided on based of the least *ranked* type in the below list

> - `int`
> - `unsigned int`
> - `long int`
> - `unsigned long int`
> - `long long int`
> - `unsigned long long int`

which can hold (*represent*) the value.

Also, for the very reason, `sizeof(0xF)` is the same as `sizeof(int)` which happens to produce a result of `4` in your platform.

Comment: which suffix i should put it to be unsigned short?

Comment: This isn't the reason for the compiler warning though.